# Protecting web content

Tags: asp.net, security, clipboard

I am writing a website that will be publishing content that has high IP and we would like people to pay for it. To prevent screen capture consistently, I know that there are limitations in using Javascript + flash + html.

I have discovered [artistscope](http://artistscope.com/copysafe_web_protection.asp) which seems to make it impossible to do anything of that nature. I am happy to inconvenience the user as they view my webpage but lock it down.

Does anyone have any experience with this framework?? I understand all users will have to install a plugin that some antivirus software has flagged and i'll just need to add some mark-up to the article page.

Does anyone know anything about artistscope solution and what is involved in implementing it or how well it works??

Comment: Anybody offering such a "copy-safe" solution is selling you snake oil.

Comment: People these days are weary about plugins like this, you might be happy to inconvenience them but they wont use your site. Also http://artistscope.com is written in Classic ASP, so its like a puff advertisement that they can protect content.

Comment: You may be able to stop crawling, but you can't really stop reading and typing in other notepad. Only thing you can do may be, notice with properitary dialogs and copy warnings. Isn't it?

Comment: "I'm happy to inconvenience the user as they view my webpage" Good luck with that, let me know how it works out for you in the long run. I'm sure you will have lots of customers

Comment: To all those with constructive comments thank you very much, to others who think the purpose of every site is to have a million users, not so much thanks. I am only going to have a few users who have no choice but to use this site and I want to make it as hard/agonizing as possible for them to  so @Darren Kopp the less the merrier. I have realized that you can't have the page open and type on another window using this plugin.

Comment: Its easy browse your site through a local proxy and have the proxy capture everything to disk, once your content is downloaded to your user's computers its under their control, and you really can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

If its only a few users, I'm guessing you'll require registration? if so you could use legal copyright to protect intellectual property. Use Creative common's, TradeMark your sitename, use registered post to send content to yourself before you post it online that way you can prove in a court that its plagiarized and you were the first to copyright it. This sort of reminds me of this article: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Lock-and-Key-.aspx and maybe your site should be in stone, a safe or as a MagicEye. As Greg mentioned there is no bullet proof solution, guys like us will come along and write auto-OCR readers to scan your site and get foreigners to run the app. If you had a legal notice, I'd at least think twice.

Edit: maybe you could even get creative with Captcha's too to deter people (when you detect copyright infringement), here's an idea to two: [Is there an efficient algorithm for segmentation of handwritten text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015001/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-for-segmentation-of-handwritten-text/8018169#8018169)

Comment: The problem is that if one user shares this info say via email, this can lead to a lot of lost revenue. So my primarily goal is to make it as difficult as possible given the limitations on the web for someone to copy the content.

Answer (score 0):

I also have used Artist Scope solutions, but when it comes to screenshot, it is not enough.

I've just written [this post](http://ijassar.info/wordpress/how-i-copy-protected-my-wordpress-content) about protection against screenshot and other content grabbing methods like snipping tool. I'll update it soon for other protection methods that I followed in my blog.

**Here's a general description of my approach:**

1. It only works for restricted content; content that needs registration to view it.
2. It requires continuous monitoring by the administrator because...
3. It detects screen print key and sends an email to you with the username and other details of the person that has already captured your content (If you are aware of any method that bans the user automatically, I'd be glad to hear it).
4. It covers your content with an overlay if the user tries to capture it while outside the browser window.