# Remove high frequency vertical shear noise from image

Tags: image-processing, noise, noise-reduction

I have a some scanned images, where the scanner appears to have introduced a certain kind of noise that I've not encountered before. I would like to find a way to remove it automatically. The noise looks like high frequency vertical shear. In other words, a horizontal line that should look like `------------` shows up as `/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\`, where the amplitude and frequency of the shear seem pretty regular.

Can someone suggest a way of doing the following steps?

1. Given an image, identify the frequency and amplitude of the shear noise. One can assume that it is always vertical and the characteristic frequency is higher than other frequencies that naturally appear in the image.
2. Given the above parameters, apply an opposite, vertical, periodic shear to the image to cancel this noise.

It would also be helpful to know how these could be implemented using the tools implemented by a freely available image processing package. (Netpbm, ImageMagick, Gimp, some Python library are some examples.)

**Update:** Here's a sample from an image with this kind of distortion. Actually, this sample shows that the shear amplitude need not be uniform throughout the image. :-(
The original images are higher resolution (600 dpi).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem would be to convert the image to frequency domain using FFT. The result will be two matrices: the image signal amplitude and the image signal phase. These two matrices should have the same dimensions of the input image.

Now, you should use the amplitude matrix to detect a spike in the area tha corresponds to the noise frequency. Note that the top left of this corner of this matrix should correspond to low frequency components and bottom right to high frequencies.

After you have indentified the spike, you should set the corresponding coefficients (amplitude matrix entries) to zero. After you apply the inverse FFT you should get the input image without the noise.

Please provide an example image for a more concrete (a practical) solution to your problem.

Comment: I have read that in an excellent image processing book. The peak removal would be to "erase" the brightest (perhaps darkest, depending on convention) spots on the amplitude matrix, and then use the corrected matrix to transform the image back.

Comment: The Image Processing Handbook (CRC Press), 6th edition, chapter 6, figure 6.26 - Removal of Periodic Noise

Comment: Alceu & heltonbiker, thanks for the suggestion. I've considered this option, but the following problem springs to mind. The noise is not of additive, which would be the case if it could be efficiently represented as `noisy image = true image + noise`. It shows up as vertical shear, where entire pixel columns are shifted up and down in a periodic way, that is `noisy image = shear transform(true image)`. I think it would be better for image integrity to cancel the noise by applying another shear transform, rather than additively.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Hough fit or RANSAC to fit lines first. For Hough to work you may need to "smear" the points using Gaussian blur or morphological dilation so that you get more hits for a given (rho, theta) line in parameter space.

Once you have line fits, you can determine the relative distance of the original points to each line. From that spatial information you can use FFT to find help find a "best fit" spatial frequency and then shift pixels up/down accordingly.

As a first take, you might even skip FFT and use more of a brute force method:

1. Find the best fit lines using Hough or RANSAC.
2. Determine the orientation of the lines.
3. Sampling perpendicular to the (nominally) horizontal lines, find the points along that column with respect to the closest best fit lines.
4. If the points along one sample are on average a distance +N away from their best fit lines, shift all the pixels in that column (or along that perpendicular sample) by -N.

This sort of technique should work if the shear is consistent along a vertical sample, but not necessarily from left to right. If the shear is always exactly vertical, then finding horizontal lines should be relatively easy.

Judging from your sample image, it looks as though the shear may be consistent across a horizontal line segment between a 3-way or 4-way intersection with a nominally vertical line segment. You could use corner detectors or other methods to find these intersections to limit the extent over which a pixel shifting operation takes place.

A technique I posted here is another way to find horizontal stretches of dark pixels in case they don't fall on a line:
[Is there an efficient algorithm for segmentation of handwritten text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015001/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-for-segmentation-of-handwritten-text/8875390#comment11276759_8875390)

All that aside, is there a chance you could have the scanner fixed?

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote if I had the reputation. This looks helpful, though I first have to read up on the methods you suggest. Fixing the scanner would have been the easiest option. Unfortunately, it was a old, clunky microfiche reader from the library, which I don't believe is fixable by mere mortals. :-/

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you get stuck and I'll try to help out.